# Regex command to remove numbers after decimal place and replace other special character such as £?

Tags: java, regex

Regex command to  remove numbers after decimal place and replace other special character such as £?

Example Before the change has been implemented: "£233.555"
After change has been implemented (£ removed, numbers after decimal place removed): "233"

I have the following code but dosnt seem to do the job, please note im using the regex replaceAll within java as listed:

```
Long.parseLong(list.get(i).getText().replaceAll("[£ [.0]+$]", ""
```

Comment: Use `.replaceFirst("(£\\d+).*", "$1")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Probably more like `.replaceAll("(£\\d+)\\.\\d+", "$1") `, no?

Comment: @DenysSéguret Both will work, there are a lot of other patterns that will work, too.

Comment: wait, replace '£' by '£', aren't they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex :

```
£(\d+)\.\d+
```

and replace with `$1`

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/sfmZ0a/5)

Sample java [code](https://ideone.com/OJzyBQ)

```
String val = "£233.555";
System.out.println(val.replaceAll("£(\\d+)\\.\\d+", "$1"));
// OUTPUT : 233
```

**Explanation**

- **`£(\d+)`:** Match £ followed by 0+ digits, capture only the digits.
- **`\.\d+`** Match a dot followed by 0+ digits, don't capture anything.

Comment: what do you mean by removing the £? you dont want it in the final string?

Comment: sorry was my mistake i need to remove any £, I have updated my original question